# Do I need Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header when requesting from subdomain of same domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I have a WordPress site on a root domain, using the WordPress API I am pulling in data from a subdomain of the root domain - do I need to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header matching this subdomain? If so - is there a way to add multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header's for each subdomain.

Example:

**WordPress site:** https://www.example.com

**Other site** https://test.example.com

Do I need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header of https://test.example.com on https://www.example.com even though it's on the same main domain?

I have obviously tried with and without, and 90% of the time without the request does succeed, but intermittently it fails, so I'd like to understand if it is required or not.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header matching this subdomain?

Yes. A different subdomain is a different hostname so it is a different origin.

> is there a way to add multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header's for each subdomain.

Not as such.

Either:

- use `*` to allow everything *or*
- read the `Origin` header from the request, check it against a whitelist, then generate the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` using the value from the `Origin` header

Comment: Thanks for lightning response good idea with the whitelist - I'll do this. However - the request does seem to succeed 90% of the time - and when it doesn't it seems to be because the subdomain is caching the preview page origin and sending that instead of the actual origin. If it's sent correctly as the subdomain, it does succeed